# Add 1 to a number represented as an array of digits, using recursion

Tags: java, array, recursion

> Given a non-negative number represented as an array of digits, plus one to the number.
>   The digits are stored such that the most significant digit is at the head of the list.

Explanation for using array vs ArrayList:

I could have used ArrayList and that would have been simpler while appending a 1 at the beginning but I wanted to use arrays only as the functions declarations were given and I didn't want to keep converting list to array and vice versa there by adding another O(n) operation.

Any feedback is appreciated. I know there are similar questions in other languages and using iterative approach, but I want feedback on my particular approach.

```
public class plusOne {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        plusOne obj = new plusOne();
        int[] digits = {0};
        int[] result = obj.plusOne(digits);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }

    public int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {
        int length = digits.length-1;
        return increment(digits, length);
    }

    public int[] increment(int [] digits, int index) {
        if(digits[index]!=9)
        {
            digits[index]+=1;
            return digits;
        } else {
            if(index==0) {
                int[] newDigits = Arrays.copyOf(digits,digits.length+1);
                newDigits[digits.length] = 0;
                newDigits[index]=1;
                return newDigits;
            }
            digits[index] = 0;
            return increment(digits, index-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, please be consistent: `int[] digits` is the norm, but you also wrote `String args[]` and `int [] digits`.  Classes are normally named with an initial uppercase (`PlusOne`).  It is also customary to put a space before and after binary operators and after each comma, as well as after the `if` keyword.

There isn't any point in instantiating a `plusOne` object, when all you want is a function.  Therefore, you should have `public static int[] plusOne(int[] digits)`.  The `increment` function is a helper; it should be `private static int[] increment(…)`.

It's weird that the operation usually operates on the array in place, but sometimes writes "junk" to that array then returns a new one.  Perhaps that is a consequence of the nature of the problem, but it's an issue that should be clearly documented in JavaDoc.

In Java, it is usually preferable to **avoid recursion** (due to concerns about stack overflow and performance) if the problem can also be easily solved using iteration — as this problem can.  If you do use recursion, though, I recommend structuring the code to make it more obvious that there are two base cases and one recursive case.  The way the `index == 0` case sets `newDigits[digits.length] = 0` feels weird: it doesn't work locally the way recursion should.  If you're going to make the assumption that it's OK to plop a `0` at the end, you might as well assume that you want a `1` followed by `0`s everywhere else, in which case you could just do `new int[digits.length + 1]`.

```
public class PlusOne {

    private PlusOne() {}  // Suppress the default constructor

    /**
     * Adds one to an integer that is represented as an array of digits
     * (most-significant digit first).
     *
     * @return The returned array may or may not be the same array
     *         as the input.  In either case, the contents of the
     *         input array will be overwritten.
     */
    public static int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {
        return increment(digits, digits.length - 1);
    }

    private static int[] increment(int[] digits, int index) {
        if (digits[index] != 9) {
            digits[index] += 1;
            return digits;
        } else {
            digits[index] = 0;
            if (index > 0) {
                return increment(digits, index - 1);
            } else {
                int[] newDigits = new int[digits.length + 1];
                newDigits[0] = 1;
                return newDigits;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't pay attention to formatting much but I should have. I wanted to do recursive since that's my weak area. With iterative approach, I can do easily. Your solution is clearer than mine. Thank you for taking the time to provide the review.

Comment: @200_success What's the space complexity of this problem when done recursively? Should be O(n) isn't it? And what about the space complexity when done iteratively?